# How to get parent text value from child's value node in XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How can I get the UUID from the `addressinformation` (in this case **999123**) where the address name is "BILL_TO" (if any) with Java XPath?

Here is my XML:

```
    <Company>
        <Name>My Company</Name>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
        <street>123 Main Street</street>
        <AddressInformation>
                <UUID>543233<UUID>
            <Address>
                <UUID>223223</UUID>
                <AddressID>
                    <AddressName>Default</AddressName>
                </AddressID>
            </Address>
        </AddressInformation>
        <AddressInformation>
                <UUID>999123<UUID>
            <Address>
                <UUID>443211</UUID>
                <AddressID>
                    <AddressName>BILL_TO</AddressName>
                </AddressID>
            </Address>
        </AddressInformation>
        <city>Mytown</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11234</zip>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 3):

ok first off your XML wasn't well formed so I fixed this it for you

```
 <Company>
    <Name>My Company</Name>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
    <street>123 Main Street</street>
    <AddressInformation>
            <UUID>543233</UUID>
        <Address>
            <UUID>223223</UUID>
            <AddressID>
                <AddressName>Default</AddressName>
            </AddressID>
        </Address>
    </AddressInformation>
    <AddressInformation>
            <UUID>999123</UUID>
        <Address>
            <UUID>443211</UUID>
            <AddressID>
                <AddressName>BILL_TO</AddressName>
            </AddressID>
        </Address>
    </AddressInformation>
    <city>Mytown</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <zip>11234</zip>
</Company>
```

then this is the xpath which should do the trick for you:

```
//Company/AddressInformation[Address/AddressID/AddressName='BILL_TO']/UUID
```

Comment: and to get the text of the UUID element: //Company/AddressInformation[Address/AddressID/AddressName='BILL_TO']/UUID/text()

Comment: I've been working with XML for 11 years now and I can't recommend XMLSPY enough if you think you will use XML/XSL alot, then XMLSPY is king!

Comment: @dnault no, if you want the string value of the `UUID` element then you simply evaluate the original xpath in the answer _as a string_ - for `javax.xpath` this means `XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(expression, domDocument, XPathConstants.STRING)`. The `text()` location step will give you a set of all the individual text node children of a given node, which is rarely what you really want (for example passing such a set to a function expecting a string will operate only on the _first_ node in the set, not the whole text value of the element).